# Marital Alliance vs Marriage

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

The following text comes from the Wiki page for [**Yukio Mishima**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukio_Mishima) where both **marital alliance** and **marriage**(to marry) are mentioned in the same sentence.

> After briefly considering a **marital alliance** with Michiko Shōda (who later married Crown Prince Akihito and is now Empress Michiko[13]), Mishima **married** Yoko Sugiyama on June 11, 1958.

On searching for **marital alliance** the definition is given as **marriage**.

Why not use

> After briefly considering **marriage** with
>   After briefly considering **getting married** to

Is the term **marital alliance** being used in deference to the Empress or is there something else going on that is only implied?

Comment: I believe a _marital alliance_ is a marriage arranged among royalty for reasons other than love, such as political expediency.

Comment: @JR +1 I see where you are coming from. The backstory is that the Empress is the first commoner to marry into the Japanese Royal Family. At the time Mishima was considering marriage, both were commoners, but the *arranged marriage* description does fit what was possibly happening at the time with the Empress' parent's wishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Marital alliance** is a marriage arranged among royalty for reasons other than love, such as political expediency.

The backstory is that the Empress is the first commoner to marry into the Japanese Royal Family.

At the time Mishima was considering marriage, both of them were commoners. The arranged marriage description, might fit what was happening at the time with the Empress' parent's wishes since they seemed to be very picky about her suitors, even though they were commoners.